# ¿Como calcular los valores acumulados de un Json?

Tags: javascript, json

Tengo un json que me devuelve un array con una fecha y medidas. Dentro de las medidas hay valores que quiero consolidar, luego de ordenar los datos por mes.

```
obj {
    0:{
      'timestamp': "2016-01-02T08:13:00+00:00",
      'measure':{
        'calories': {
          'text': 'cals',
          'unit': 10
        },
        'steps': {
          'text': 'm',
          'unit': 10
        }
      }
    },
    1:{
      'timestamp': "2016-01-03T08:13:00+00:00",
      'measure':{
        'calories': {
          'text': 'cals',
          'unit': 30
        },
        'steps': {
          'text': 'm',
          'unit': 30
        }
      }
    },
    3:{
      'timestamp': "2015-12-31T08:13:00+00:00",
      'measure':{
        'calories': {
          'text': 'cals',
          'unit': 15
        },
        'steps': {
          'text': 'm',
          'unit': 15
        }
      }
    },
    4:{
      'timestamp': "2015-12-31T08:13:00+00:00",
      'measure':{
        'calories': {
          'text': 'cals',
          'unit': 40
        },
        'steps': {
          'text': 'm',
          'unit': 40
        }
      }
    },
}
```

Básicamente este es el array con los objetos que me devuelve, con momentJS he formateado el año y logrado filtrar por mes, pero no he logrado alguna forma de agrupar y sumar el measure de cada uno de los meses, teniendo en cuenta que cada mes tiene sus días

result esperado

```
  {
        'timestamp': '2016'
        'month': 'jan',
    'measure':{
            'calories': {
          'text': 'cals',
          'unit': 20 // valor consolidado de cada dia
        },
        'steps': {
          'text': 'm',
          'unit': 20 // valor consolidado de cada dia
        }
    },
    'timestamp': '2015'
        'month': 'dec',
    'measure':{
            'calories': {
          'text': 'cals',
          'unit': 20 // valor consolidado de cada dia
        },
        'steps': {
          'text': 'm',
          'unit': 20 // valor consolidado de cada dia
        }
    }
```

Que metodos podria usar para resolverlo, he intentado con lodash pero sin lograr resultados completos

Answer (score 2):

> Básicamente este es el array con los objetos que me devuelve, con momentJS he formateado el año y logrado filtrar por mes, pero no he logrado alguna forma de agrupar y sumar el measure de cada uno de los meses, teniendo en cuenta que cada mes tiene sus días.

Ante todo, no es un array, es un objeto. Un array de objetos tiene la notación `[ {}, {} ]` y este objeto tiene la notacion `{ 0: {}, 1: {} }`.

Aclarado esto, aquí te dejo un ejemplo que utiliza [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/keys) y [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce) para obtener la sumatoria de todas las calorías y los pasos.

Básicamente `Object.keys` lo uso para obtener las key del objeto (`[0,1,2,3]`) así luego lo puedo tratar como si fuera un array. (Ojo! Quizá seria mejor que lo obtengas como array directamente desde el servidor, si acaso puedes cambiarlo).

Luego uso `Array.reduce` sobre ese array resultante, para iterar sobre todos los elementos e ir obteniendo el valor acumulado.

Ya que lo tienes resuelto, no sera difícil de modificar para poner un filtro por la fecha y darle el formato exacto que necesitas. Deje algunos comentarios en el código del stack snippet que te ayudaran a hacerlo.

Nota: Esto no require librerías adicionales ya que es parte de ES2015, pero puede requerir un polyfill para que funcione en navegadores viejos.

```
Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(prev, key) {

  prev.calories += obj[key].measure.calories.unit;
  prev.steps += obj[key].measure.steps.unit;

  return prev;   

}, { calories: 0, steps: 0 }); // <<-- valor inicial es prev
```

Ten en cuenta que si quires usar `lodash` o similar, la sintaxis seria muy parecida.

```
_.reduce(Object.keys(obj), function(prev, curr) { 
  // ... lo mismo
}, { calories: 0, steps: 0 });
```

```js
var obj = {
  0: {
    'timestamp': "2016-01-02T08:13:00+00:00",
    'measure': {
      'calories': {
        'text': 'cals',
        'unit': 10
      },
      'steps': {
        'text': 'm',
        'unit': 10
      }
    }
  },
  1: {
    'timestamp': "2016-01-03T08:13:00+00:00",
    'measure': {
      'calories': {
        'text': 'cals',
        'unit': 30
      },
      'steps': {
        'text': 'm',
        'unit': 30
      }
    }
  },
  3: {
    'timestamp': "2015-12-31T08:13:00+00:00",
    'measure': {
      'calories': {
        'text': 'cals',
        'unit': 15
      },
      'steps': {
        'text': 'm',
        'unit': 15
      }
    }
  },
  4: {
    'timestamp': "2015-12-31T08:13:00+00:00",
    'measure': {
      'calories': {
        'text': 'cals',
        'unit': 40
      },
      'steps': {
        'text': 'm',
        'unit': 40
      }
    }
  },
};


function reduceWithoutFilter() {
       
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(prev, key) {
    // esto dentro de un if y ya tienes un filtro, pero
    // quiza te conviene hacerlo en una etapa separada, es cuestión de diseño.
    prev.calories += obj[key].measure.calories.unit;
    prev.steps += obj[key].measure.steps.unit;
    return prev;   
  }, { calories: 0, steps: 0 }); // <<-- valor inicial es prev
  
}

console.log(reduceWithoutFilter());
```

Answer (score 0):

Aquí tienes un ejemplo de cómo hacerlo con moment y lodash.

Utilizo moment para obtener el mes y año de la fecha.

Con el método groupBy de lodash realizo una agrupación por mes.

Con el método reduce de lodash realizo la suma de las unidades de cada día.

Finalmente con el método map devuelvo la nueva colección.

```js
        var obj = {
            0: {
                'timestamp': "2016-01-02T08:13:00+00:00",
                'measure': {
                    'calories': {
                        'text': 'cals',
                        'unit': 10
                    },
                    'steps': {
                        'text': 'm',
                        'unit': 10
                    }
                }
            },
            1: {
                'timestamp': "2016-01-03T08:13:00+00:00",
                'measure': {
                    'calories': {
                        'text': 'cals',
                        'unit': 30
                    },
                    'steps': {
                        'text': 'm',
                        'unit': 30
                    }
                }
            },
            3: {
                'timestamp': "2015-12-31T08:13:00+00:00",
                'measure': {
                    'calories': {
                        'text': 'cals',
                        'unit': 15
                    },
                    'steps': {
                        'text': 'm',
                        'unit': 15
                    }
                }
            },
            4: {
                'timestamp': "2015-12-31T08:13:00+00:00",
                'measure': {
                    'calories': {
                        'text': 'cals',
                        'unit': 40
                    },
                    'steps': {
                        'text': 'm',
                        'unit': 40
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        var grouped = _.groupBy(obj,
            function(el) {
                var dat = moment(el.timestamp);
                return dat.year().toString() + '_' + dat.format('MMM');
            });
        var accum = _.map(grouped,
            function (measures, key) {
                return _.reduce(measures,
                    function(accumulator, el) {
                        accumulator.measure.calories.unit += el.measure.calories.unit;
                        accumulator.measure.steps.unit += el.measure.steps.unit;
                        return accumulator;
                    },
                    {
                        timestamp: key.split('_')[0],
                        month: key.split('_')[1],
                        measure: {
                            calories: { text: 'cals', unit: 0 },
                            steps: { text: 'm', unit: 0 }
                        }
                    });
            });

        console.log(accum);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.12.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: gracias esta bien, pero en el objeto timestamp y month que resulta de la funcion acum, puedo firmatear el timestamp para que presente el año en formato javascript y el mes con momentjs para que presente ppor jemplo Apr May etc, ose a la function acum le podria pasar el la variable obj obtener y filtrar con momentjs estos valores?

Comment: No entiendo exactamente lo que quieres hacer. Para tener en el resultado el mes en texto abreviado no tendrías más que cambiar la creación de la clave en el groupBy. Edito el código para dejarlo así.